# Erlang equivalent of javascript codePointAt?

Tags: erlang

Is there an erlang equivalent of codePointAt from js? One that gets the code point starting at a byte offset, without modifying the underlying string/binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bit syntax](https://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html) pattern matching to skip the first N bytes and decode the first character from the remaining bytes as UTF-8:

```erlang
1> CodePointAt = fun(Binary, Offset) ->
  <<_:Offset/binary, Char/utf8, _/binary>> = Binary,
  Char
end.
```

Test:

```erlang
2> CodePointAt(<<"πr²"/utf8>>, 0).
960
3> CodePointAt(<<"πr²"/utf8>>, 1).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value <<207,128,114,194,178>>
4> CodePointAt(<<"πr²"/utf8>>, 2).
114
5> CodePointAt(<<"πr²"/utf8>>, 3).
178
6> CodePointAt(<<"πr²"/utf8>>, 4).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value <<207,128,114,194,178>>
7> CodePointAt(<<"πr²"/utf8>>, 5).
** exception error: no match of right hand side value <<207,128,114,194,178>>
```

As you can see, if the offset is not in a valid UTF-8 character boundary, the function will throw an error. You can handle that differently using a `case` expression if needed.

Comment: It seems like this is often (but not always) a constant time operation, which should be good enough for me. https://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/binaryhandling.html#sub-binaries

Comment: I believe this will always be constant time as the two `/binary` we construct are bound to `_` and the compiler should not generate code for those parts.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that only binary strings are using UTF-8 in Erlang. Plain double-quote strings are already just lists of code points (much like UTF-32). The unicode:chardata() type represents both of these kinds of strings, including mixed lists like `["Hello", $\s, [<<"Filip"/utf8>>, $!]]`. You can use `unicode:characters_to_list(Chardata)` or `unicode:characters_to_binary(Chardata)` to get a flattened version to work with if needed.

Meanwhile, the JS codePointAt function works on UTF-16 encoded strings, which is what JavaScript uses. Note that the index in this case is not a byte position, but the index of the 16-bit units of the encoding. And UTF-16 is also a variable length encoding: code points that need more than 16 bits use a kind of escape sequence called "surrogate pairs" - for example emojis like  - so if such characters can occur, the index is misleading: in `"az"` (in JavaScript), the `a` is at 0, but the `z` is not at 2 but at 3.

What you want is probably what's called the "grapheme clusters" - those that look like a single thing when printed (see the docs for Erlang's string module: https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html). And you can't really use numerical indexes to dig the grapheme clusters out from a string - you need to iterate over the string from the start, getting them out one at a time. This can be done with `string:next_grapheme(Chardata)` (see https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#next_grapheme-1) or if you for some reason really need to index them numerically, you could insert the individual cluster substrings in an array (see https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/array.html). For example: `array:from_list(string:to_graphemes(Chardata))`.

Comment: Good explanation with all the background needed for anyone else finding this question, but not what I was personally looking for, since I had already read through those links.

Comment: @FilipHaglund Well, you asked for an equivalent of codePointAt from js, which works on utf-16. Do you in fact want to randomly access into a UTF-8 encoded byte sequence and try to decode what's at that point, without even knowing whether it's on a character boundary? This sounds like a case where giving more details about what your end goal is could help people find a better solution.